# std::string with different encoding to QString

Tags: c++, string, qt4

Is there any way to detect `std::string` encoding?

My problem: I have an external web services which give data in different encodings. Also I have a library witch parse that data and store it in std::string. Than I want to display data in Qt GUI. The problem is that std::string can have different encodings. Some string can be converted using `QString::fromAscii()`, some `QString::fromUtf8()`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked into it but I did use some Qt3.3 in the past.

[ASCII vs Unicode + UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297704/ascii-vs-unicode-utf-8)

Utf8 is 8-bit, ascii 7-bit. I guess you can try to look into the values of string array

http://doc.qt.digia.com/3.3/qstring.html#ascii and http://doc.qt.digia.com/3.3/qstring.html#utf8
it seems ascii returns an 8-bit ASCII representation of the string, still I think it should have values from 0 to 127 or something like that. you must compare more characters in the string.

Comment: `void print_values(const char* in_string)
{
 printf("{");
 for (int i= 0; in_string[i]!= 0; i++)
 {
  printf("%d", in_string[i]);
  if (in_string[i+1] != 0)
   printf(", ");
 }
 printf("}\n");
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 QString test("iNyuu");
 const char* ascii = test.ascii();
 const char* utf8 = test.utf8();
 printf("ascii = "); print_values(ascii);
 printf("utf8 = "); print_values(utf8);
 return 0;
}`
// never mind, I see "QCString utf8 () const" (utf doesn't return char array here & not sure for Qt4
// you used "operator std::string () const"?
// try similar stuff with std::string