# How do I convert a byte array with null terminating character to a String in Kotlin?

Tags: string, kotlin, character-encoding, null-terminated

When I attempt to retrieve a value from the device via Bluetooth, it comes out in ASCII, as a null terminated big-endian value. The device software is written in C. I want to retrieve the decimal value, i.e. 0 instead of 48, 1 instead of 49, 9 instead of 57, etc.

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun receiveData(socket: BluetoothSocket ? ): Int {
 val buffer = ByteArray(4)
 val input = ByteArrayInputStream(buffer)
 val inputStream = socket!!.inputStream
 inputStream.read(buffer)

 println("Value: " + input.read().toString()) // Value is 48 instead of 0, for example.

 return input.read()
}
```

How can I retrieve the value I want?

Comment: This will _definitely_ depend on the encoding of the string written in C.

Comment: It will, but I used a stock bluetooth chat app to receive the signal and it does receive all 5 integers. I only receive 1 with my application. I suppose I need to know how it is encoded in order to decode it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to do with [`bufferedReader`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/buffered-reader.html):

```
val buffer = ByteArray(4) { index -> (index + 48).toByte() }     // 1
val input = ByteArrayInputStream(buffer)

println(input.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() })            // 2
// println(input.bufferedReader().use(BufferedReader::readText)) // 3
```

[Will output](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/m4m9k6nou6d0iavsh4jq9v5vju/oh3fnqmb2ldqsqhbj9rr9jl2hv) "0123".

**1**. Just stubs the content of a socket using an init function that sets first element of the `buffer` to 48, second to 49, third to 50 and fourth to 51.

**2**. The default charset is UTF-8, that is a ["superset" of ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21297794/750510).

**3**. It's just another style of calling `{ it.readText() }`.

Answer (score 1):

My function ultimately took the following form. This allowed me to retrieve all 5 digits in decimal form:

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun receiveData(socket: BluetoothSocket ? ): String {
 val buffer = ByteArray(5)
  (socket!!.inputStream).read(buffer)
 println("Value: " + String(buffer))
 return String(buffer)
}
```

For my particular problem, the input variable was being created before reading the data into the buffer. Since the read method is called for every index in the data, I was only getting the first digit.

See the Java method `public int read()` for an explanation:

`Reads the next byte of data from this input stream. The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0 to 255. If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been reached, the value -1 is returned.`